# Case class equals with list of byte array

Tags: scala

I am trying to use the should matchers on a case class

```
case class ListOfByteArrayCaseConfig(

  @BeanProperty 
  permissions: java.util.List[Array[Byte]]

)
```

With the following test case

```
val orig = ListOfByteArrayCaseConfig(List(Array[Byte](10, 20, 30)))
val orig2 = ListOfByteArrayCaseConfig(List(Array[Byte](10, 20, 30)))

orig2 should be === orig
```

Obviously this would fail because the two byte arrays are not equal reference wise.  What I want to do is somehow make this work without changing the test case code and still keeping the case class.

Is it even possible?  (like adding a custom equals method to the case class?)

Comment: You are using ScalaTest or Specs2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.  Apparently I can override the equals method in a case class

[Scala: Ignore case class field for equals/hascode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373715/scala-ignore-case-class-field-for-equals-hascode)

Though it gets rid of the reason for using case classes in the first place which is to simplify data objects.

```
case class ListOfByteArrayCaseConfig(

  @BeanProperty 
  permissions: java.util.List[Array[Byte]]

) {

  override def equals(arg: Any): Boolean = {

    val obj = arg.asInstanceOf[ListOfByteArrayCaseConfig]
    var i: Int = 0
    for (i <- 0 until permissions.size()) {
      if (!util.Arrays.equals(permissions.get(i), obj.permissions.get(i))) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, but you should not assume that object passed to `equals()` is of `ListOfByteArrayCaseConfig` type. Moreover, consider using pattern matching instead of downcasting.

Comment: You had better override `hashCode` also if you plan on using this with sets or maps (or just want `hashCode` and `equals` to be consistent).

Comment: True, I just wanted a quick and dirty class to be used for testing, but I agree it needs a hashCode and a proper equals implementation.  At the very least this shows what can be done.