# Scala hex literal for bytes

Tags: scala, literals, scala-2.12

Hex literal containing A-F digit are converting to int by default. When I am trying to declear an Int with **0x** it is creating correctly.

```
val a: Int = 0x34
val b: Int = 0xFF
```

But when I am trying to declear a Byte with **0x** second line is not compiling

```
val a: Byte = 0x34
val b: Byte = 0xFF // compilation error
```

I have found a workaround that is

```
val a: Byte = 0x34
val b: Byte = 0xFF.toByte
```

But is there any **decent** way to declear a Byte from its hex literal?

For example I am trying to declear a Byte array in a Test method in this way

```
anObject.someMethod(1, 1.1f, 0xAB, "1") shouldBe
  Array[Byte](0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF)
anObject.someMethod(2, 2.2f, 0xCD, "2") shouldBe
  Array[Byte](0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE, 0xBE)
anObject.someMethod(3, 3.2f, 0xEF, "3") shouldBe
  Array[Byte](0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD)
```

But not in this way

```
anObject.someMethod(1, 1.1f, 0xAB.toByte, "1") shouldBe
  Array[Byte](0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte, 0xAF.toByte)
anObject.someMethod(2, 2.2f, 0xCD.toByte, "2") shouldBe
  Array[Byte](0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte, 0xBE.toByte)
anObject.someMethod(3, 3.2f, 0xEF.toByte, "3") shouldBe
  Array[Byte](0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte, 0xCD.toByte)
```

Tested in scala 2.12.4

Comment: You might want to take a look at [different ways to define byte *arrays* instead of single bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010140/how-to-declare-a-byte-array-in-scala).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with implicit conversions.

Before:

```
def f(b: Byte) = println(s"Byte = $b")
f(0x34)
f(0xFF) // compilation error
```

After:

```
implicit def int2Byte(i: Int) = i.toByte

def f(b: Byte) = println(s"Byte = $b")
f(0x34)
f(0xFF)
```

Output:

```
Byte = 52
Byte = -1
```

Answer (score 5):

Recall that in Scala we can easily define new ways to interpret arbitrary  `String` literals by adding methods to a special class `StringContext` using the "pimp-my-library"-pattern. For example, we can add the method `b` for creating single bytes to `StringContext` so that we can write down bytes as follows:

```
val myByte = b"5C"
```

Here is how it can be implemented:

```
implicit class SingleByteContext(private val sc: StringContext) {
   def b(args: Any*): Byte = {
     val parts = sc.parts.toList
     assert(
       parts.size == 1 && args.size == 0, 
       "Expected a string literal with exactly one part"
     )
     Integer.parseInt(parts(0), 16).toByte
   }
}
```

In order to use this new syntax, we have to import the above object into implicit scope. Then we can do this:

```
/* Examples */ {

  def printByte(b: Byte) = println("%02X".format(b))

  printByte(b"01")
  printByte(b"7F")
  printByte(b"FF")
  printByte(b"80")
}
```

This will print:

```
01
7F
FF
80
```

You can obviously tweak the implementation (e.g. you can rename "b" to "hex" or "x" 
or "Ox" or something like this).

---

Note that this technique can be easily extended to deal with entire *byte arrays*, as described [in this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010140/how-to-declare-a-byte-array-in-scala/48936165#48936165). This would allow you to write down byte arrays without repeating the annoying `0x`-prefix, e.g.:

```
val myBytes = hexBytes"AB,CD,5E,7F,5A,8C,80,BC"
```