# Scala mutable set: strange behavior

Tags: scala, set

I can't explain this behavior of Scala sets.

Let's start with a few definitions.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Set
case class Item(name: String, content: Set[Int])
val items: Set[Item] = Set.empty
```

I'll add an item to my set.

```
items += Item("name", Set(1, 2, 3))
```

I'll empty my inner set.

```
items.filter(_.name == "name") foreach (_.content -= 1)
items
// res7: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set(Item(name,Set(2, 3)))
```

So far so good.

```
items.filter(_.name == "name") foreach (_.content -= 2)
items.filter(_.name == "name") foreach (_.content -= 3)
items
// res12: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set(Item(name,Set()))
```

Perfect! Now, what I REALLY want to do is remove the entries with an empty inner set.

```
items.retain(_.content.nonEmpty)
items
// res12: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set(Item(name,Set()))
```

Didn't work. Maybe I did the opposite test.

```
items.retain(_.content.isEmpty)
items
// res14: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set(Item(name,Set()))
```

Didn't work either. Maybe the filter doesn't work.

```
items.filter(_.content.nonEmpty)
// res15: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set()
```

The filter works fine. Maybe I can't change it because it's a val.

```
items += Item("name", Set.empty)
items
// res17: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set(Item(name,Set()), Item(name,Set()))
```

I CAN change it. And add... more of the same? Maybe they're all different.

```
items += Item("name", Set.empty)
items
// res19: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set(Item(name,Set()), Item(name,Set()))
```

They're not all different. So can I remove any of them?

```
items -= Item("name", Set.empty)
items
// res21: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set(Item(name,Set()))
```

I can remove ONE. Can I remove the other, the one I've been trying to remove from the start?

```
items -= Item("name", Set.empty)
items
// res23: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Item] = Set(Item(name,Set()))
```

Nope. What's happening? I'm very confused.

EDIT, SOLUTION:

Using this Stackoverflow post, [Scala: Ignore case class field for equals/hascode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373715/scala-ignore-case-class-field-for-equals-hascode), I solved this by changing the way I declare the case class:

```
case class Item(name: String)(val content: Set[Int])
```

This way, the inner set is disregarded for hashcode and equals evaluations, but still accessible as a field.

Comment: Don't ever import `mutable.Set` only ever import `mutable` then use `mutable.Set` in the scope. This is best practice because mutable should be avoided like the plague and to make it really explicit to any reader that your using mutable types.

Comment: I tried to avoid mutable, but it just became necessary at some point. The other solution is to make the content field a `var`, and that seems much worse. Also, the value is only ever changed or queried upon getting a message in a specific actor `object`, so at least there's no real concurrency problem.

Comment: Yes of course sometimes it is nice, particularly for low level optimizations or to avoid using recursion. The point was that you should simply make it very explicit by using `mutable.Set`, abd also u shouldnt pollute the namespace as the default is `immutable.Set`

Comment: I did change the code today as you suggested, @samthebest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashcode of `Item` changes when you change `content`. Since a set created by `Set(...)` is a hash set, it can't work correctly if hashes of its elements change. Note that it doesn't matter whether the `Set[Item]` is mutable or not; only that `content` is mutable.

If you put mutable objects into a hash set or use them as keys of a hash map, you *must* make sure that either 1) they aren't mutated while there or 2) their `hashCode` method is stable.

Comment: Just checked it. If you override hashcode with i.e. name.size it works.

Comment: @goral `name.hashCode` would be a bit better.

Comment: Tried hashcode, no wonder it didn't work. Either way I just wanted to check it :)

Comment: I was sure that equality and hash values were recalculated every time. Well that explains that. Also, the case class didn't have its own set until recently, so I didn't plan it that way, it just happened. On the upside, it did teach me more about Scala. Thanks.

Comment: "I was sure that equality and hash values were recalculated every time." Yes, they are. That's precisely the problem: the element is still stored under its old hash value, but is looked up by the current hash value.